# It is formally correct to say the elements of a vector space are vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, notation, terminology, definition

A vector space $\small \mathbb V$ is the association of a set of vectors and a set of scalars (or a field), e.g:

- $\small \mathbb R^3$ for the vectors,
- $\small \mathbb R$ for the scalars,

with addition and scalar multiplication satisfying the vector space axioms.

Indeed, for any vector $v$ of this example: $v \in \mathbb R^3$. However it's common to see statements like $v \in \mathbb V$. E.g:

[From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space):

> In mathematics and physics, a vector space (also called a linear space) is a set whose elements, often called vectors, may be added together and multiplied ("scaled") by numbers called scalars.

---

**My questions**. Is it correct to say:

- a vector space is a set?
- vectors are elements of the vector space?

Comment: Yes vectors are elements of a vector space.

Comment: If you define a vector space as a tuple $(V,F,+,\ldots)$ as you suggest in the first paragraph then the elements of $V$ are called vectors and it is correct to write $v\in V$. I have not seen anyone refer to the whole tuple as $V$.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek I have. Though I've also seen it written like $V=(\mathcal V,F,+,\cdot)$ with the adage that $v\in V\iff v\in\mathcal V$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Saying that a vector space is a set whose elements can be added etc. can be seen as a remnant of an "Eulerian" worldview. In this view, objects such as numbers have an inherent concept of arithmetic operations such as addition and multiplication. $2 + 3 = 5$ no matter whether you are considering the integers or the complex numbers, and they are the same $2$, $3$ and $5$. In this worldview, being a vector space is a [property](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/stuff,+structure,+property). A set is either a vector space, or it's not.

Modern mathematics tend to take an alternative worldview. Here, the elements of a set has no internal structure, $2 \in \mathbb R$ is merely a label for an element, and switching labels around doesn't affect mathematics whatsoever. To meaningfully talk about addition on $\mathbb R$, you need to *equip* it with additional [structure](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/stuff,+structure,+property), i.e. the structure of a function $\textsf{add} : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$. In this worldview, a set can become a vector space in multiple ways.

So saying a vector space $\mathcal V$ "is" a set doesn't make sense, in the say way that saying a two dimensional point $(x,y)$ "is" the real number $x$ doesn't make sense. Since there may be different points $(x,y_1), (x, y_2)$ that have the same $x$.
Similarly, an inner product space $\mathcal V$ isn't a vector space, and a metric space isn't a topological space.
To contrast this, it *does* make sense to say a finite-dimensional vector space $\mathcal V$ is a vector space, since being finite dimensional is a property. And a *metrizable* space is a topological space.
This distinction of *stuff, structure and property* has already occurred to many mathematicians, and it is articulated and promoted by John Baez, Michael Shulman and others.

With this in mind, it's easy to see why saying "a vector is an element of a vector space" is a correct but less-than-useful statement. Given a mathematical object $v$, it is no inherent property of $v$ that $v$ belongs to some vector space. You can construct any set $V$ with $v$ in it, and $v$ will become a vector in $V$. What's more useful is saying "$v$ can be viewed as a vector **in the vector space $V$**". This is telling the reader to think about $v$ in a different and possibly fruitful way.

Of course, usually when people say "Let $V$ be a vector space", what they usually mean is "Let $(V, +, \times, \dots)$ be a vector space", and the letter $V$ actually refers to the *set* instead of the vector space. So notations such as $x \in V$ or $W \subset V$ makes sense because they are really just notations of sets. But this is just a matter of trivial notation fiddling, and doesn't bear much value unless there is danger of confusion.

Comment: Then how would you discuss subspaces? Surely when checking whether $U$ is a subspace of $V$, one requires first that it be a subset of $V$?

Comment: @PaulAsh Does this contradict with something that I said? Can you point that out so I can clarify?

Comment: Never mind, I initially misunderstood your last paragraph. Although, I'm still not convinced that a vector space is not a set. Yes, it's a set that is laid with a structure of addition and scalar multiplication, but it's still a set. Would you say a ring is not a set?

Comment: @PaulAsh Yes, a ring is not a set, in the exact same way. It can be *turned into a set* by a canonical function, but that doesn't mean it *is* a set.

Comment: I hope @mins gives this answer the green checkmark, because this is the best answer I ever read on Mathematic stack exchange.

Comment: This answer might be valid at some Philosophical level (so no downvote from me !) , though my answer is valid at some other Practical level more suited to OP Query. OP can give the check-mark to whichever answer , @Fomalhaut , so no objections from me there , though meanwhile we might dispose all the textbooks written by Vinberg , Blyth & Others which give the opposing view !

Comment: @Prem You are trying to equate me disagreeing with a certain minor claim in their textbooks with me completely discrediting the entire books. These two are not the same, and it is not helpful to conflate them.

Answer (score -1):

It is always true that when $v$ is a vector , then $v \in V$.

It may sometimes "additionally" be true that $v \in R^3$ , when the vectors are 3D real numbers.
In that Case , $V=R^3$.

In general , w might have "larger vectors" like 5D or 9D, then Eg $v \in R^5$ , $v \in R^9$
In that Case , $v \not \in R^3$

Even more generally , we might have vectors over "Integers & Booleans & rationals" & Etc , Eg $v \in Z^3$ & $v \in \{0,1\}^5$ & $v \in Q^9$.
In that Case , $v \not \in R^3$ & $v \not \in R^n$

---

"Is it correct to say a vector space is a set, and vectors are the elements of the vector space?" : YES , it is always true.

" ... vector $v \in V$ , but actually $v \in R^3$ . I see no ambiguity here ... " : NO , it is not always true. It might or might not be true.

---

### ADDENDUM 1 :

**"A Course in Algebra" by E. B. Vinberg**

Example Page 24 :
"Definition 1.53. A vector (or linear) space over a field $K$ is a set $V$ with operations of addition and multiplication ...."
" .... Elements of a vector space are called vectors"

Example Page 25 :
"Definition 1.57. A subset $U$ of a vector space $V$ is called a subspace if
(i) $U$ is a subgroup of the additive group $V$;
(ii) $a \in U$ $\implies$ $\lambda a \in U$ for any $\lambda \in K$"

Example Page 26 :
"Definition 1.62. A system of vectors $\{e1, e2, ... , e_n \} \subset V$ is called a basis of $V$ if every vector $a \in V$ can be uniquely expressed as a linear combination of $e_1, e_2, \cdots , e_n$. Coefficients of this expression are called coordinates of $a$ in the basis $\{e_l, e_2, \cdots ,e_n\}$ ...."

### ADDENDUM 2 :

Additional Confirmation is available via "Basic Linear Algebra" by Blyth & Robertson :

Unlike the earlier reference , where I typed out the text , here I will use a snippet to colorize & high-light the relevant wordings & symbols :

[image: 69]

Comment: Your first sentence answers my question: the vector space is also a set, that's what was not clear to me. I'm using $\small \mathbb R^3$ as an example, indeed there are vectors not in $\small \mathbb R^3$.

Comment: I have added Examples , @mins , where "$\in V$" & "$\subset V$" are highlighted !

Comment: I have to disagree: A vector space is not a set.

Comment: Do you disagree with me or with E. B. Vinberg ? Check out [[ https://books.google.com/books?id=kd24d3mwaecC ]] to review the text book which has the line "A vector (or linear) space over a field K is a **set V** with operations ..." , @Filippo , the Author is very clear there !!

Comment: I have added new reference with similar usage , @Filippo , there are numerous such references.

Comment: A vector space is not a set. Saying so is only a convenient abuse of language.

Comment: If A is a B (e.g. an even number is an integer), then whenever two A are different, then they must be different when considered as B. An integer can't "be" an even number $x$ and an even number $y$ and have $x\ne y$
. But a set can become a vector space in non-equivalent ways.

Comment: I am only the messenger , the message was given by Vinberg & Blyth & Robertson & numerous others , @Trebor , hence you are not just disagreeing with me , but with highly qualified mathematicians !

Comment: Sure, I can give some names of more highly qualified mathematicians to back me up. But being highly qualified as mathematicians doesn't mean they are highly qualified as mathematical philosophers.

Comment: Last Comment ((A)) Can you share some references which show I am wrong ? ((B)) The given mathematicians are not isolated crackpots , these text books have been used in many universities which agree with the content ((C)) If there are opposing views , then which government or which organization decides who is right and who is wrong ? ((D)) Without that , @Trebor , these views are valid & right !!

Comment: I'm not saying that anybody is a crackpot. But "governments deciding what math is correct" is just ridiculous. I'm writing an answer, will publish shortly.

Comment: Vinberg does not say that a vector space is a set (if that was the case, then vector spaces would not be a new concept). He says that a $K$-vector space $V$ is a set with two operations. To define a vector space, it is not enough to specify a set - you also need to specify the addition and the scalar multiplication. The point is that you can define different vector space structures on the same set (there are even some sets that do not admit any vector space structure), so you need to specify the addition and the scalar multiplication to prevent any ambiguity.

Comment: For example, if a function is linear w.r.t. one particular choice of vector space structures, this doesn't mean that it is linear w.r.t. to any choice of vector space structures.